# In IText7, { display:inline !important; } css is not working as expected when creating PDF from HTML

Tags: css, itext7

I'm trying to create PDF from HTML(String) using iText 7.1.7. When I copy the HTML in W3Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default), I see the css[display:inline !important;] works fine and **displays the 3 div sections inline**. But, when I generate the PDF with my sample java program using the same HTML through iText7, it is **displaying the 3 div sections as block**. Does iText7 have issues with CSS? If not, can you please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

***Note: You might want to replace all \" with " in HTML before you test it in W3Schools***

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Sample Java program:**

```
private static final String SAMPLE_HTML = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"> <html> <head></head> <body><!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <style> div.fp-soft-merge, p.fp-soft-merge { display: inline !important;   }</style></head><body><div class=\"fp deletable free-tag fp-hard-ln-init fp-soft-merge\" data-fp=\"FREE\" data-paragraph-timestamp=\"2014-08-01\" data-paragraph-type=\"FREE\"><p class=\"fp-hard-ln-init\" style=\"text-align:justify\"><br></p><p class=\"fp-hard-ln-init fp-soft-merge\" style=\"text-align:justify\">The applied-for mark MARK1 and the registered mark MARK2 are similar because they would be pronounced in the same manner. Some other sample content for Testing purpose. Specifically, both have a \"ock\" first syllable followed by a \"ee\" syllable.&nbsp;</p></div><div append-br=\"true\" class=\"fp deletable fp-soft-merge fp-hard-ln-init\" data-delete-selector=\"[data-fp=Q29-34]\" data-fp=\"Q29-34\" data-paragraph-timestamp=\"2011-05-13T03:00:52.000-04:00\" data-paragraph-type=\"FREE\"><p class=\"fp-soft-merge fp-hard-ln-init\" style=\"text-align:justify\"><span>The marks are essentially phonetic equivalents and thus sound similar. Similarity in sound alone may be sufficient to support a finding that the marks are confusingly similar. </span><i>In re Hand Wine Ltd.</i><span>, 4 XYPQ5e 1400, 1300 (XBAB 1966); </span><i>see In re 1st USA Some other, Inc.</i><span>, 89 XYZQ8j 1500, 1466 (ABAB 5607); TMEP &#167;1677.05(b)(iv).</span></p></div><div class=\"fp deletable free-tag fp-hard-ln-init fp-hard-ln fp-soft-merge\" data-fp=\"FREE\" data-paragraph-timestamp=\"2014-08-01\" data-paragraph-type=\"FREE\"><p class=\"fp-hard-ln fp-hard-ln-init fp-soft-merge\" style=\"text-align:justify; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0\"><span>&nbsp;The marks are likely to be confused because they sound the same.</span><br></p><p class=\"fp-hard-ln-init\" style=\"text-align:justify\"><br></p></div></body></html>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream;
    try {
        byteArrayInputStream = convertToPDF(SAMPLE_HTML.getBytes());
        IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, new FileOutputStream("./src/test/resources/PDF_HTML_0.pdf"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ByteArrayInputStream convertToPDF(byte[] htmlContent) throws IOException {
    if(htmlContent != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos, getDefaultWriterProperties());
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent), pdfDocument);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private static WriterProperties getDefaultWriterProperties() {
    WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
    writerProperties.setCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    return writerProperties;
}
```

Comment: Following are the imports in case you need:import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.CompressionConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.WriterProperties;

Comment: Any help resolving this would be great. Thank you.